# DropDownList not selecting items hidden on scroll overflow in popup (Kendo ui Angular2)

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, dropdown, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using:

- "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^0.27.8"
- "@angular/core": "2.4.3"

I've got a dropdownlist with more than 20 items.
[image]

When I click on the dropdownlist the popup appears. Only the first 10 items are visible, the rest are hidden under the popup overflow.

If I select an item that is visible, there is no problem and the item gets selected.
[image]

This is the item selected:

[image]

**The problem:**

When I click on a item that initially was not visible in the popup scroll, that item does not get selected. How come?

[image]

As you can see I've scrolled down the popup, to select an item hidden by the overflow. As a result the "default item" or the "previously select item" stays selected. Clearly not the expected behaviour. I believe it's a bug, any workaround is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I know it's been over a year since you asked this question. But I'm dealing with this now even with version 3.0.2 of kendo's angular dropdowns. Did you ever determine why it was happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the component works just fine with the latest `@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns@0.29.0`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="example-wrapper">
      <p>T-shirt size:</p>
      <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems">
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
   </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
   public listItems: Array<string> = [];

   ngOnInit() {
     this.listItems = new Array(100).fill("Item").map((s, i) => s + i);
   }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Us7LagIZ2M0gMjmsYzGH?p=preview

Could you try to update the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out my problem, and I suspect yours was the same. If you use a function as a data source and then try to scroll down and select an item further down the list, it doesn't select and pops you back to the top of the list.

https://plnkr.co/edit/dKHILUdPFB383jln5cYM?p=preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems()">
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public listItems(): Array<number> { return  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]; }
}
```

Comment: I currently have the same exact same problem. Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Yeah, you can't use a function as a data source. This way works https://next.plnkr.co/edit/c7niqxP39jiFruOc